# Detect redirection within iframe

Tags: html, angular, typescript, iframe

I need to detect when my iframe did not get served the content it requested but instead got redirected to the login page.

Does the iframe even handle the redirection or is this done by the browser?
What led me to believe so: the load event only gets fired once + even afterwards it's src property is still set to the original URL.

Comment: If on the same origin, have the login page tell the parent OR have the login page redirect to _top when loaded

Comment: Sorry, can you explain further?

Comment: `function isFramed() { try {
        return window.self !== window.top;
    } catch (e) {
        return true;
    }; if (isFramed) window.open(location.href,"_top");`

Comment: or `function isFramed() { try {
        return window.self !== window.top;
    } catch (e) {
        return true;
    }; if (isFramed) parent.doSomethingWhenLoginIsFramed()`

Comment: If you control the content of the iFrame you can use the postMessage standard: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: Works quite well, many thanks @mplungjan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming same origin you have these two ways given this test:

```
function isFramed() {try {return window.self !== window.top;} catch (e) {return true;};
```

This

```
if (isFramed) window.open(location.href,"_top");
```

or

```
if (isFramed) parent.doSomethingWhenLoginIsFramed();
```

Alternatively look at [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)